# Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to deny all and allow only for a single IP. But, I would like to have the following htaccess working for that single IP. I'm not finding a way to have both working: the deny all and allow only one, plus the following options:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

Comment: NOTE! Apache is sensitive for spaces in htaccess. Do not allow any space between deny,allow. I.e do not write order deny, allow.

Comment: INFO: - it works for IPv6 too! just add another line with `allow from yourIPv6`

Comment: Is it possible in nginx?

Comment: @hajder : how to do the opposite : deny three given ips and allow all others?

Comment: @sqlchild check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html. Basically you can probably add three lines of 'Deny from xxx' followed by 'Allow from all'.

Comment: How do you add more IP addresses?

Comment: @Pathros see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess#46171069

Comment: [Note on 2.4 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html): _The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use._

Comment: As @MA-Maddin pointed out, - then mod_access_compat are deprecated. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865658/htaccess-allow-deny-ip-using-require-apache-2-4) shows how to do in newer versions. And one should also be considering, if the server is using a proxy, since that would then display the proxy-IP for the visitor. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356187/apache-2-4-require-ip-not-working) suggests a solution to that.

Comment: if you have more than one just add separating with coma, 1:1:1:1:1:1,2:2:2:2:2

Comment: How about deny a country but allow one or three IP address on that country?

Answer (score 159):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) says:

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

So, a more future-proof answer would be:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.yy
</RequireAll>
```

Hopefully, I've helped prevent this page from becoming one of those "outdated tutorials". :)

Comment: Where do we put our IP?

Comment: Way to go! This should be accepted solution as it's not only working but also timeproof.

Comment: The other answer didn't help in my situation. But this one did. Thanks, for updating an old thread.

Comment: This answer's example allows access from two IP's? So, to add multiple IP's we just put a space between them? Can you put `Require ip` on multiple lines to make it more user readable or do all IP's have to be on one line?

Comment: if you used this, how would you redirect to a new temp page as some of the answers did?

Comment: So, this didn't work for me, but `order deny,allow` did. Is the format supposed to be `Require ip 54.228.197.221`?

Comment: Turns out that I had to enclose it in `<RequireAny>` tags to make it work.

Comment: Hmm, it returns an `Internal Server Error` for the IPs not listed.

Answer (score 43):

This can be improved by using the directive designed for that task.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /specific_page.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Where 111.222.333.444 is your static IP address.

When using the "Order Allow,Deny" directive the requests must match either Allow or Deny, if neither is met, the request is denied.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order

Comment: how to add acustom uRL?

Answer (score 34):

Slightly modified version of the above, including a custom page to be displayed to those who get denied access:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /specific_page.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

...and that way those requests not coming from 111.222.333.444 will see specific_page.html

(posting this as comment looked terrible because new lines get lost)

Comment: Hi. I have the exact same code as you have in my .htaccess but I'm keep getting a 500 error. The page I specified is called `test.html` and is in the same folder as the `.htaccess`. However, I can't see the logs (not allowed from server). Do you have any idea why I could have that problem? When I'm getting the path of the file via an ftp client it tells me `/test.html` so the path shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Also, the 500 error comes even when I have the line with the errordocument commented out. So that shouldn't be the problem. Is there a reason the other 3 lines could not work? In my .htaccess I have three more lines, where I redirect non-www to www, but that's it. But I'm also getting the error when I have ONLY the three lines with deny, allow, etc.

Comment: How to add acustom URL?

Answer (score 9):

Improving a bit more the previous answers, a maintenance page can be shown to your users while you perform changes to the site:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /maintenance.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from #.#.#.#
```

Where:

- `#.#.#.#` is your IP: [What Is My IP Address?](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)
- For `maintenance.html` there is a nice example here: [Simple Maintenance Page](https://gist.github.com/pitch-gist/2999707)

Comment: When I use the ErrorDocument 403 I get an additional 403 error for that maintenance.html file, because it cannot access that file neither. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 7):

Just in addition to @David Brown´s answer, if you want to block an IP, you must first allow all then block the IPs as such:

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require not ip 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
  Require not ip 172.16.0.0/12
  Require not ip 192.168
</RequireAll>
```

- First line allows all
- Second line blocks from `10.0.0.0` to `10.255.255.255`
- Third line blocks from `172.16.0.0` to `172.31.255.255`
- Fourth line blocks from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255`

You may use any of the notations mentioned above to suit your CIDR needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is the proper way to deal with Apache 2.4!

Comment: how to deny from all but allow only specific IPs according to this new syntax?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following command in .htaccess file. And place that file in your htdocs folder.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from <your ip> 
Allow from <another ip>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from set your IP
```

[using htaccess to restrict access by ip](https://expertsnote.com/web-development/using-htaccess-to-restrict-access-by-ip/)

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to use the 403 method because I wanted the maintenance page and page images in a sub folder on my server, so used the following approach to redirect to a 'maintenance page' for everyone but a single IP*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !**.**.**.*
RewriteRule !^maintenance/ http://www.website.co.uk/maintenance/ [R=302,L]
```

Source: [Creating a holding page to hide your WordPress blog](https://www.thetwopercent.co.uk/2010/03/creating-a-holding-page-to-hide-your-wordpress-blog/)

Comment: This solution is the simpliest - I prefer it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in htaccess to allow and deny access to your site :

```
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^1\.2\3\.4\.5$ allowedip=1

Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=allowedip
```

We first set an env variable **allowedip** if the client ip address matches the pattern, if the pattern matches then env variable **allowedip** is assigned the value **1** .

In the next step, we use Allow,deny directives to allow and deny access to the site.  `Order deny,allow` represents the order of `deny` and `allow` . `deny from all` this line tells the server to deny everyone. the last line  `allow from env=allowedip` allows access to a single ip address we set the env variable for.

Replace `1\.2\.3\.4\.5` with your allowed ip address.

Refrences :

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html

Comment: What are the pros of using this instead of just Allow From 324.234.22.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one IP or even some other kind of allow like user, hostname, ... more info here https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setenvif/

```
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^123.123.123.1$ allowedip=1
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^123.123.123.2$ allowedip=1
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^123.123.123.3$ allowedip=1
SetEnvIf remote_addr ^123.123.123.4$ allowedip=1

Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=allowedip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /maintenance.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from #:#:#:#:#:#
```

For me, this seems to work (Using IPv6 rather than IPv4) I don't know if this is different for some websites but for mine this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mod_rewrite for access control you can use condition like user agent, http referrer, remote addr etc.

Example

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=*.*.*.* #you ip address
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

Refrences:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Answer (score 0):

As of Apache 2.4's latest updates, the Allow, Deny, and Order directives are deprecated: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

If using Apache 2.4, here is an example to deny all access but one whitelisted IP:

```
Require all denied

<RequireAny>
   Require ip 10.0.0.1
</RequireAny>
```

Really this can be in any order though. Here's another example:

```
<RequireAny>
   Require ip 10.0.0.1
</RequireAny>
<RequireAll>
   Require all denied
</RequireAll>
```

I had to play around with this until I figured it out, but here is another website that provided more examples:
https://htaccessbook.com/access-control-apache-2-4/