# How to restrict the staging environment in Openshift from being accessed by others

Tags: cloud, openshift, staging, test-environments

I have been reading about release management for Openshift and have found a nice process described in Openshifts official blog. According to this process you develop the application locally, then deploy it to a staging environment and in the end, when everything is working, you deploy it to production.

The information I am looking for, but can't find, is how to restrict the access to the staging environment. This environment should only be used by me to test the application in a production-like environment and should not be accessible by other people. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What cartridge/language is your application written in?

Comment: I am thinking on using the PHP catridge and put wordpress on it. If possible I would prefer a general answer which does not depend on what catridge is used. Maybe there is a way to configure the gear, for instance that you also need to create a tunnel to even access port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PHP cartridge allows you to do this in a couple of different ways:

- **Using an .htaccess file**

  - **Basic Auth** - You can use htaccess basic authentication to restrict access to your site.  You will be asked for a username/password to access your sites content.  You can learn more about Basic Authentication here: http://engineering.oregonstate.edu/computing/web/43 and you can build your .htaccess file here (http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/) You can use action hooks (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html) to move the .htaccess and .htpasswd files into place when you deploy your website to staging, i would suggest based on an environment variable of some kind.
  - **Allowed IP Address** - You can also use an .htaccess file to allow only your ip address to access that website ([.htaccess block all but my ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934768/htaccess-block-all-but-my-ip)) which seems like it would be the most convenient way, unless your ip address changes a lot.  You can use the same action hook method to move the .htaccess file into place based on the existence of an environment variable.
- **Using PHP**

  - You can also use php code to block access to your website by checking the visitors ip address, along with the existence of an environment variable something like:

  if ($visitors_ip != "x.x.x.x") {
      exit();
  }