# deny and allow ip access .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip

Seen lots of info regarding this but can't figure out this scenario. I want to deny all uk ips but allow my own uk ip.

I have a big list of deny ip addresses which work fine and deny access, but I want to be able to access the site for obvious reasons!

Basically I'm creating a site for Irish consumer base and the owner wants to exclude the UK from accessing the site. But I need to access it still.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934768/htaccess-block-all-but-my-ip

Comment: No I need to deny from a list of ips from the uk and allow from one ip from the uk. I cant deny all as I need other countires to see the site.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file put this rule in same manner and write your ip's which are whitelisted in allow from your ip

```
<Directory "/">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from 127.0.0.1
   allow from 127.0.0.2
</Directory>
```

Using Require

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 10.252.46.165
</RequireAll>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: I dont want to deny all.... i have a list of deny ips but not all. Deny list of uk ips but allow this uk ip and all other ips

Comment: Instead of all you can put ip's which you want to deny.

Comment: yes I did that but it took down the site e.g. instead of allow all deny ip 2.2.2.2deny ip 3.3.3.3. I put... alow ip 5.5.5.5deny ip 2.2.2.2deny ip 3.3.3.3