# .htaccess deny from all allow from one IP not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am struggling for weeks with .htaccess for one of my websites.

All I want is to allow one certain IP on the website and block everything else.

I'm using this code from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13938692

So:

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from 123.456.789.123
Deny from all
```

It's not making an exception for 123.456.789.123. Everything is blocked without exceptions.

If I do

```
Deny from 123.456.789.123
```

Then this IP is indeed blocked, but the code I pasted above that is recommended all on the net is not working for me

I also tried:.

- Order Allow,  Deny (without space after the period) this one bugs my site no matter what I enter afterward, so I guess space is the proper version.
- Require (not changing anything).

example

```
Require all denied
Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Can someone help me out please :(>)-(

Comment: Did you try: `order deny,allow`     `deny from all`      `allow from 123.456.789` ?