# Close an area of just me

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

it is such that I need to convert my website to a new version but it is into the folder named "/public_html/opdaterning" but it is such that I do not want others even me access to the folder out of myself . I try to do like this but it helps nothing .. :(

```
ErrorDocument 403 /specific_page.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 111.222.333.444
```

[Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip)

Comment: The question you linked has a working answer, but you're not using it.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: in my eyes so it just wrong to close the area that I had been thinking about me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

for multiple either extra allow lines or seperated with spaces

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
allow from 111.111.111.111 111.111.111.112
```

and for the critics, i know an ip can not contain 333 or 444 ;)

Comment: Can I do so that it can be more IPs?

Comment: Thanks for help. 

but it is such that it appears with error 403 in since then. how can I do so that you will be forwarded / to google or facebook or face all my own.

Comment: with the solution you already posted: "ErrorDocument 403 /specific_page.html" and in the specific_page.html force the user to redirect, perhaps first with a nice notice that you are gonna do this, not to confuse the user.

Comment: i have add its here on my .htaccess fil : `ErrorDocument 404 /www.absb.dk/`