# Can't Restrict/Allow Properly With .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to restrict access to a specific folder with htaccess. This is something I thought was fairly simple, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I'd like to allow my ip address access and deny all others, but it isn't letting me in and is instead blocking everyone access. Is there a setting somewhere that might need to be changed to make this work properly? My code:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Access Control"
AuthType Basic
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I've also tried:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Both, and a few other variations, block everyone but don't allow my ip address access.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What you have in your last code sample should work.  If you just do "allow from all" -- are you let in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip

Comment: That lets me in. It also lets everyone else in, though, right? Essentially negates itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Satisfy    any
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This still doesn't let me in.