# htaccess show one page to certain IP

Tags: php, .htaccess

We are working on a development site and want to show a holding page to all visitors whilst we make the final changes.

Can I use htaccess to show one index page to the outside world and the main index to our internal team?

Comment: Yes. See bottom two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule ^ maintenance.html [L]
```

This says *if the remote address is not 1.2.3.4, answer any request with `maintenance.html`*.