# Intranet IP Lockdown

Tags: .htaccess, ip, intranet

I only want **people to access the intranet from my IP**.

I have searched different blogs as well but not get more.

I **just want my website to be accessed by just my IP address to make it secure**. I need an intranet that can be **locked down by IP**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`), changing the `999...` to your IP address:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^999.999.999.999
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`