# only allow my IP to view site htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the following code in my htaccess but it is not working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^144\.124\.152\.167
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/soon\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /soon.php [R=302,L]
```

I used the following to figure out my remote_host

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
```

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip

Answer (score 3):

Create .htaccess file and code the following lines.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <Give YOUR IP>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `.htaccess` and add the following code:

```
order allow,deny
allow from <Give YOUR IP>
```

If the deny is the last parameter then everything is denied and you can allow every client. Then you don't need the line `deny from all`