# disabling access to website temporary for all visitors Except myself

Tags: php, .htaccess

for technical reason and test new features on my PHP website I want to disable access usual users to website temporarily and show a message like **'Site is Under Maintenance'**.

However I want to be able to access all pages and I have normal usages.
How can I do that with htaccess , php codes or other methods?

Comment: Just allow your  ipaddress to access the page. for example $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; if($ip !="yourip"){echo "Site is Under Maintenance";}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find answer here:

[Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip][1])

> or you can do it by **PHP** also:

if your own ip is : 10.233.34.12

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != '10.233.34.12'){
  header("Location: http://example.com/siteUnderMaintenance.php");
 die();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1 //your IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.11\.11\.111 //your server IP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logo\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /soon.htm [R=301,L]
```

Use this in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2):

Allow only your IP. Try to put it in your .htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Or you could use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

The above code sends all users to maintenance.html EXCEPT those with the specified IP.

Comment: and if OP has apache 2.4 or later?

Comment: how can I show a message or redirect users to construction page in this method?

Comment: @ahmad, Blocked visitors will be shown a '403 Forbidden' error message. You can customize this error message by updating 'Error Documents'.

    `ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/403.html`

Comment: @Harshit Shrivastava, I try your first code in htaccess along to `ErrorDocument` on localhost and create 403.html page on the root like this : `ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 31.58.64.19` , however 31.58.64.19 is my ip, I can not open pages and shown *Forbidden* default message.