# .htaccess allow/deny ip using require apache 2.4

Tags: .htaccess

My hosting provider recently updated the server to Apache 2.4 and the rules to control access to a specific folder via .htacces file doesn't work anymore with this code:

```
Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from All
 Allow from 123.123.123.123
 Allow from 123.123.123.123
 Allow from 123.123.123.123
```

After reading Apache 2.4 documentation I understand i should use something like this instead:

```
<RequireAny>
Require ip 123.123.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
</RequireAny>
```

but it doesn't work. Any one who can help me figuring this out? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For 2.4 it now looks something like this:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
Require ip 123.123.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
</RequireAll>
```

EDIT:

```
Require ip 123.123.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
```

A document describing information critical to existing Apache HTTP Server users.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick answer. I used your proposed code in a .htaccess file inside wp-admin folder in order to block access to any ip other than the ones listed in the file, but still can't access wp-admin connecting from any of the mentioned ip's. Anything else i'm missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Hey @AlbertoEstévezdeCastro, I've just had a look. With 2.4 you should be able to just add `Require ip 123.123.123.123` into your .htaccess files. Thus meaning that it requires xyz address to access. Please see my edit on answer.

Comment: Hi thickguru, in fact this was my very first approach after reading the Apache 2.4 documentation my provider referred me to, but no luck either. I'm lost. If anything else comes to your mind, pleas let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @AlbertoEstévezdeCastro Check out this link [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html) it's a document describing information critical to the upgrade, first section is allow deny etc and how it has changed. I will also add it to my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thickguru, I asked my host support team for help. I will post the proposed solution asap. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Thank you for keeping me informed @AlbertoEstévezdeCastro. I'm intrigued as to why it is not currently working. Going from the documentation, what we've suggested is correct :/

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long wait. I was told by my hosting service that it wasn't working due to the fact that NginX was enabled. (Dont' know what this is) They are working on getting it to work with NginX enabled, so no matter what it is, it seems important to be enabled i guess. For now and for it to work correctly NginX has been disabled by the host IT guy.

Comment: Well, at least we now know the problem @AlbertoEstévezdeCastro and what was being suggested is correct, just server side issues. Hopefully they find a better solution for you soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution below was something that worked for me.

.htaccess

```
allow from xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.0.0/16

deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```