# Allow only an IP to specific page by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, api, ip

I have a page for API checker related to:
https://example.com/?sts_auth
I want to only the server can check this page. How can I do this by .htaccess file?

Comment: probably duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sts_auth$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

Replace your desired IP in the `127\.0\.0\.1` (For example, if your IP address is `123.12.1.345`, you would change it to `123\.12\.1\.345`)

The `F` in `[L,F]` will cause a `Forbidden (403)` Error

Comment: I tested but not worked! my subpage is /?sts_auth and I want to show 403 error for other IPs.

Comment: How can I add more IPs?