# Heroku: restrict access to files in public/ by IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, heroku, source-maps

I've got an app on Heroku that contains uglified JS code. I'd like to include my original sources (.js) in my public folder so that I can refer to them from a source map for debugging. I don't want the source files to be viewable by just anyone, however: I'd like to restrict access to a certain set of IPs.

In other words, in my Rails app on Heroku I'd like to have a file here:

`myapp.herokuapp.com/unminified_sources/my_file.js`

And I'd like to restrict access to this file to a certain IP (mine).

Is this possible on Heroku? How? Can I use [an .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400412/765287)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file behind a `unminified_sources_controller` `my_file` action that responds to js requests and restrict it that way.  You can restrict in the route or add a before_filter to test for IPs.

You can stream the file.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#sending-files