# Deny all IPs but one

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I'm trying to block all IP'sbut my own but it doesn't work for me.
I use the following code as answered in [Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess)

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from MyIP
```

But it lets other IP's access too.
My IP is static and my site is hosted by a thirth party hosting service

Comment: I already checked and my .htaccess file is loaded cause my rewrite rules work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your ip is static or not, Please try it like this,

```
<Files ~ ".*">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

`127.0.0.0` denotes your localhost.

**Edit**

Remove access rule and try it with mod_rewrite,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111$ #your IP
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: its not for a local website and my ip is static

Comment: Localhost means your system on which site is hosted even if it is live website, and if your ip is static then it should work, where are you denying the access please provide full rule.

Comment: but when my site is hosted by a thirth party it doesn't work, which is the case here

Comment: after some more testing I discovered my code works for all but index.php, what could be the problem?

Comment: I asked you to show full rule like you are denying the access to directory or group of files after that i am able to tell.

Comment: I showed my full rule, I wanna deny access to all files in the site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131233/discussion-between-abhishek-gurjar-and-paul-roefs).

Answer (score 0):

If you did the following code:

`order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from MyIP`

and it also allowed other peoples ips then it has something to do with your host. Cause I ran the code on my site and it worked fine.