# Only allow a certain domain to access my php files

Tags: php, cors

I am trying to prevent a php file from being accessed directly through a browser or anything else, unless its coming from a authorised domain.

I used the php header Access-Control-Allow-Origin like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
```

But it still doesn't block direct access.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to .htaccess method:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

and this one too:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip <your ip> 
</RequireAll>
```

I also tried using both with domain names.

With this I managed to block direct access, but I also blocked my app from accessing it too.

I get:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and I added:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myappdomain.com');
```

Still not working.

Comment: you should look into using [`.htacess` files](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) if your host allows them

Comment: You could always set up a function to check your database for trusted domains that have been added in? This way you can have an admins section also to add the trusted domains in.

Comment: @happymacarts Yes it does. Its a dedicated server. I remember trying htaccess but I couldn't get it to allow access to the file from other domain.

something like this:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess)

Comment: `accessed directly through a browser or anything else` I have to say: Then setting just an `header()` will not work. Because a User can always write a url into a browser. You have to prevent the acces via `.htaccess` or with something like @Antony has shown.

Comment: @happymacarts I think you just gave me the answer with that thread link. I'll try that.

Comment: CORS and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and all other `Access-Control-*` headers intentionally doesn’t prevent users from directly navigating to a URL—any more than they prevent anybody from using curl or whatever to get to it. CORS and those headers only affects cross-origin scripted requests to the URL, using XHR or the fetch API.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?
Sample code:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'gooddomain.com'){
    die('Unauthorized access');
}
```

Although this can be manipulated or altered quite easily, unless you control both the sending and the receiving server there isn't much more you can do.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be manipulated and can be empty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: Unless there is a unique key or authentication mechanism requiring you to control the other domain, everything can be manipulated.

Comment: Some routers actually clears the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` header for privacy reasons.

Comment: `everything can be manipulated` so only use trustfull data if possible ;)