# Is it possible to make phpmyadmin be able to authorize including user's IP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

Is it possible to make phpmyadmin authorize including user's IP?

Actually, on my server, it is possible to login to phpmyadmin with any user/password that is allowed to "localhost" in privileges.

I want to only allow users with special IP to login to phpmyadmin. I am using debian. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure about PhpMyAdmin. But that can be done with a rule in htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess

Comment: I want to not allow to login to phpmyadmin users that are not having same ip as in phpmyadmin's privileges.

Comment: Actually phpmyadmin is letting to login any user that is having "localhost" in host data. I want to make phpmyadmin listen to IP of someone who is trying to log in and if ip of this user is not in privileges, deny him from login.