# Allow/block access to a specific path with apache 2.4 failing

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apache2.4

I have a  django website project deployed in an enviroment from AWS Beanstalk. 
I'm trying write configs to apache block access to a specific path (/admin).
I avoid change wsgi.conf file, instead I writing package.config in .ebextensions folder, like following:

```
"/etc/httpd/conf.d/block_admin.conf":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
  <Location /admin>
     <RequireAll>
         Require ip <my_ip>/32
         Require all denied
     </RequireAll>
  </Location>
```

That code is denying all access to "/admin", include from my ip.
I get my ip from services like [what is my ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/).

What am i doing wrong?

PS: My english is a working in progress....

**[edit]**

I tryed change the order of Require(all denied/ip) directives

Comment: Have you searched the web before  ? looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess or even https://serverfault.com/questions/714887/how-to-forbid-access-to-admin-url-path-in-apache-config-by-ip-subnet

Comment: Thanks, but i ask here after some hours (or days) from search here or in internet.  That linked question is from 2010 and his recently answers not help me or bring a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `<RequireAll>` or multiple `Require` directives at all, simply `Require ip 1.2.3.4`.  If it continues to fail, read the error_log entry closely each time.