# Access image folder from Laravel Project A to Laravel B, C, D etc

Tags: laravel, public, shared-directory

Let's say I have main project Laravel A, which stores photos of employees. I need the rest of the Laravel projects B, C and so on to access or use these photos from Laravel A (Like profile pictures for the rest of the projects). All of these projects are running in a single server locally.

How the rest of the projects access the photos of employees from Laravel A?

Comment: Make storage folder shared - move it outside of projects make symlink. OR use external storage like s3 or ftp.

Comment: *"running in a single server locally"* - they are different apps right? are they within the same domain as subdomains? tbh, even though they sits in the same server each app should not meddle with the other file systems directly. it would be far better if they ran on different user/permissions set.

Comment: @BagusTesa yes same domain as subdomains. i just wanted the uploaded profile pictures of Project A to be shared with other local laravel projects within the same domain. I'm just wondering if there are work arounds how to do this without degrading its security.

Comment: [tag:amazon-s3] approach would be the safest one. if you are on a budget however, write an API-only laravel app that handles user management including storing their profile shared across the app (e.g. name, profile pictures). the API should only be accessible to your app (e.g. [using IP restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703505), some kind authentication with API keys, or a full blown SSO using [oauth](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport)). consider your options wisely and take whichever suits your need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have workaround with this by creating route for photo preview on my Laravel Project A `Route::get('/photos/{filename})`, returning the image file. And by saving the uploaded photo to the storage public folder of my Project A, other projects can now access the URL like `http://projectA.com/photos/filename.jpg`.

Also by creating custom URL in my `.env` like: `IMG_URL=http://projectA.com/photos/` to all my project, I can access it like this `env('IMG_URL').filename.jpg`